# Disnake - бот приглашает других ботов на сервер где производилась команда

Tags: бот, discord

у меня возник вопрос существует ли метод который позволяет боту создавать ссылку с приглашение для другого бота и приглашать его на сервер, сам смотрел документацию, к сожалению ничего не нашёл, напишите если что-то знаете.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Подобного функционала у дискорд ботов нет и быть не может т.к. это бы создало дыру в безопасности серверов.